# JS React: replacing regex with component in a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, split

Given a string with the format:

`'This is a string with some ::FaIconUpload:: icons in it as ::FaIconDownload:: these two.'`

I'd like to split it using a RegEx and replace the coincidences with some React components. The string would have the type of component (`FaIcon`) and a props in it such as the name of the icon (`Upload`).

The objective with this is to be able to use React components within translated strings, and the **expected return value would be** something like:

```
[
  'This is a string with some ',
  <FaIcon iconName="Upload" />,
  ' in it as ',
  <FaIcon iconName="Download" />,
  ' these two.'
]
```

## The method

Currently, I've got a method which returns either a string or an array. This is compatible with React render methods, since if we return an array it will be capable of rendering any components on that array.

As I'll use it to translate some strings, I've created this custom hook:

```
const useCustomTranslation = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const tlt = (...args) => {
    // const str = t(...args);
    const testStr =
      'This is a string with some ::FaIconUpload:: icons in it as ::FaIconDownload:: these two.';
    const reg = /(?<=::FaIcon)(.*?)(?=::)/g;

    const preStrAr = testStr.split(reg);
    console.log(preStrAr);
  };

  return { tlt };
};
```

## The problem

Currently, this method is logging this:

```
[
    "This is a string with some ::FaIcon",
    "Upload",
    ":: icons in it as ::FaIcon",
    "Download",
    ":: these two."
]
```

As you can see, it's not including the `::FaIcon` and the final `::`, as I haven't been able to find the right Regex to do so. But **even if I got to that point**, I feel like then I should have to **re-iterate through the array** to replace the strings with the right component, **again using Regex** to see if the array item matches the right format.

I find this somehow overcomplicated, and I think there has to be a much cleaner and easy way to get it (correct me if maybe I'm wrong and this is the only way).

**Is there any way where I can split a string using a Regex, using part of the matched group to replace the string by another content using that matched string?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've made it using (sadly) the re-iteration method, as it's the only way I can see it would work. Thanks to [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) for his first answer, which gave me the hints to get it working:

```
export const replaceIconInStr = (str) => {
  // Matches the whole icon component pattern 
  const regComponent = /(::FaIcon.*?::)/g;
  // Matches just the component prop we need
  const regIconName = /::FaIcon(.*?)::/g;

  // Split the string by the component pattern
  const splittedStr = str.split(regComponent);

  // If there are any matches
  if (splittedStr.length) {
    // Match the elements in the array and get the prop to replace it by the real component
    return splittedStr.map((el) => {
      const matched = regIconName.exec(el)?.[1];
      if (matched) {
        return <FaIcon iconName={matched} />;
      }

      return el;
    });
  }

  // If there is no pattern matching, return the original string
  return str;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant to do this?

`/::FaIcon(.*?)::/` without the look

```js
const str = `This is a string with some ::FaIconUpload:: icons in it as ::FaIconDownload:: these two.`
const newText = str.replace(/::FaIcon(.*?)::/g,function(_,match) {
  return  `<FaIcon iconName="${match}" />`
})
console.log(newText)
```

To make an array you can do

```js
const str = `This is a string with some ::FaIconUpload:: icons in it as ::FaIconDownload:: these two.`
const newText = str.replace(/\s?::FaIcon(.*?)::\s?/g,function(_,match) {
  return  `::<FaIcon iconName="${match}" />::`
}).split("::")
console.log(newText)
```

Comment: Amazing for the first part, the issue here is that with the `replace` there you are replacing it by a string, not a React component itself, so it's going to render that as a string on the screen. But that's pretty close. I'll try to continue working from this! Thank you so much for your help!